# Waiting between events in Syn.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom-events

I use Syn.js in my tests for my website but I have a problem when I use `Syn.click` and then try to check something that happens after the event like a title change or something it doesn't work.

It's like the `onClick` event doesn't end before it begins to check what happened after.

The `onClick` function is something I can't see so I can't put a custom event to make sure it's over so I need a different way to do this.

I need a way to make sure an event ended to continue to the next line in the code without changing the event itself.

I really need an idea because I don't have a clue how to continue.

It can be in JavaScript, jQuery, whatever ....

```
  //syn.js ---- this is from the syn.js (from the internet) 
"_click": function (options, element, callback, force) {
            Syn.helpers.addOffset(options, element);
            Syn.trigger("mousedown", options, element);

            //timeout is b/c IE is stupid and won't call focus handlers
            schedule(function () {
                Syn.trigger("mouseup", options, element);
                if (!Syn.support.mouseDownUpClicks || force) {
                    Syn.trigger("click", options, element);
                    callback(true);
                } else {
                    //we still have to run the default (presumably)
                    Syn.create.click.setup('click', options, element);
                    Syn.defaults.click.call(element);
                    //must give time for callback
                    schedule(function () {
                        callback(true);
                    }, 1);
                }

            }, 1);
        }

// eventually it calls element.dispatchEvent(event); in syn.js
```

and the user use my app like this (jasmin + syn + etc...)

```
 // user code (sort off) : (doesnt work)
    Syn.click({}, button);
    expect(title).not.BeNull; // -------- here is the probleme the title need to be something but its not.
// user code (sort off) : (work)
        Syn.click({}, button);
setTimeout(function() { 
        expect(title).not.BeNull;},1000); // ----------- I need to do this but not in here ( the user cant write this it looks bad----
```

The only thing I can change is the syn.js or something in between because I don't want the user to write stuff in his code that he doesn't need.

If the user writes after every Syn.*** a setTimeout it looks really ugly and I don't want that .

I also tried setTimeout in the syn.js but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You'll probably want to show a code example if you hope to get help.

Comment: check: setTimeout() function to add delay.

Comment: In order to solve this for you, we will need to see the code that binds the click event - and the code after this that needs to wait for completion of that event (at a bare minimum). If you can create a minimal case to reproduce the issue at jsfiddle.net that would also be really helpful to help users understand your problem.

Comment: I added code sample and more explanation about what I need and do , My code is secret so I cant really show it all ( sorry )

Answer (score 0):

Ok , I found an answer, I change the code my user give me so after every syn action everything will become the callback so only when its finished the checks will begin